# Not able to come out of iFrame in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am Using MathML Editor in My Application using below code i enable to entering text into editor and it's able to Print inside the Editor but Outside of Editor There is "Ok" button so Its Showing error unable to find element, I want to click on Ok Button.?

// for Go for Editor and print into editor

```
    driver.switchTo().frame("iframeMathmlEditorcke_1");

    WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")); 

    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  

    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Hello World'", editor);
```

//for coming out of editor

```
    driver.switchTo().frame("iframeMathmlEditorcke_2");

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

/ for click on "Ok" button

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("cke_161_label")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you paste the HTML code of your webpage, that will show the arrangement of the iframes.

But the common funda is,
First come out of "iframeMathmlEditorcke_1" by switching to default frame and then switch to other frame "iframeMathmlEditorcke_2" (I am assuming that your ok button is in this iframe and these are not nested iframes).

Then try to click on the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me:

```
        final WebElement iFrame = Arrays.stream(iframes)
            .filter(frame -> frame.getAttribute("id").startsWith("iframeMathmlEditorcke")
            .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new AssertionError("Detail message what is wrong"));

        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(value);
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```